# Store the image into cache for avoiding frequent loading from url in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios5

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:
@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"];
```

**Serialisation part is done below**

```
(void)connectionDidFinishLoading{
    NSDictionary *allDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *loans = [allDict objectForKey:@"loans"];
    countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *diction in loans) {
        Country *countryObj = [[Country alloc]init];
        NSString *sector =  [diction objectForKey:@"sector"];
        countryObj.sector = sector;
        NSDictionary *imageID = [diction objectForKey:@"image"];
        NSString *img = [imageID objectForKey:@"id"];
        countryObj.idValue=img;
        NSString *activity =  [diction objectForKey:@"activity"];
        countryObj.activity = activity;
                NSString *name =  [diction objectForKey:@"name"];
        countryObj.name = name;
        NSDictionary *con = [diction objectForKey:@"location"];
        NSString *world = [con objectForKey:@"country"];
        countryObj.country= world;
        NSString *towname = [con objectForKey:@"town"];
        countryObj.down=towname;
        [countryArray addObject:countryObj];
    }
}
```

This contains both images and data. I need to store the image into cache.

Comment: user SDWebimage or AFN for load image async

Comment: this is one Request API, you need to initially sent the request to server and need to serlize the response after that follow the nitin gohel comment

Comment: i've done serialization and i've loaded it into tableview. but thing is everytime it is taking time to load from url. since i'm fresher i don't know about the SDWebimage/AFN

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: Please look top,, i've added some code for serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [SDWebImage](http://theappspace.com/caching-images-with-sdwebimage/) it contains everything you need. I am using this library for 2 years already.

Follow that tutorial which contains how to cache images inside a UIImageView with a simple one line of code and also a class that prefetches all the images in background, just create an NSArray with all the images you want to prefetch.

Hope that helps!